# Download multiple files via entries in a Vaadin Grid

Tags: java, download, vaadin

I am playing around with Vaadin and I am trying to figure out how to do a consistent way to download multiple files. So far I have created a grid with a small class, `CorrespondenceFiles`, that blueprints getters and setters that provide the structure for the grid.

However, I am unsure of how to create a downloader for multiple files and what would the best solution to this problem is. Basically, what I have done is using an `Anchor` which masquerades as a button for the download functionality.

How can I use my function iteratively or recursively to get all of the elements downloaded after being referenced from the grid?

---

Download function:

```
 public Anchor downloadButton(String btnText, String fileName) 
 {

        Button btnDownload = new Button(btnText,VaadinIcon.DOWNLOAD.create());   

        StreamResource StreamResource = new StreamResource(fileName, () -> {
            try 
            {
                return new FileInputStream(fileName);
            } 

            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{});
            } 
        });
        Anchor anchorDownload = new Anchor(StreamResource, "");
        anchorDownload.getElement().setAttribute("download", true);
        anchorDownload.add(btnDownload);

        return anchorDownload;
    }
```

---

Grid instantiation:

```
List<CorrespondenceFiles> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    fileList.add(new CorrespondenceFiles(1, mode + " - 90111", "Breakdown", "C:\\manager\\90111 - Korn, Niclas - Breakdown.pdf" ,  "90111 - Breakdown.pdf"));
    fileList.add(new CorrespondenceFiles(1, mode + " - 90111 ", "Letter of Approval", "C:\\manager\\90111 - Letter.pdf",  "90111 - Letter.pdf"));
    fileList.add(new CorrespondenceFiles(2, mode + " - 90112",  "Breakdown", "C:\\manager\\90112 - Breakdown.pdf", "90112 - 90112 - Breakdown.pdf"));

    ListDataProvider<CorrespondenceFiles> ldp = new ListDataProvider<CorrespondenceFiles>(fileList);


    grid.setDataProvider(ldp);  
    grid.addColumn(CorrespondenceFiles::getName)
        .setHeader("Name");
    grid.addColumn(CorrespondenceFiles::getDescription)
    .setHeader("Description");
    grid.addColumn(CorrespondenceFiles::getFileName)
    .setHeader("File Name");
```

NB: The **fileList** list only serves as a placeholder for database returned statements.

Comment: You can only download one file at once over http GET. If you want to download multiple files you have to pack them (ZIP or similar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having multiple files being downloaded upon one single button click is not something you should do, even if you could. This "rule" is not coming from vaadin, but counts for the whole web. The anchor element does not provide such functionality as well. There exist hacky workarounds using javascript, but you are heavily discouraged to do so.

The best way to achieve what you need is to [ZIP all the needed files](https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress), and let the user download that single zip file.